# Bootstrap navbar brand weight changes based on dropdown in Safari

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Very frustrating issue I can't figure out. Have noticed in Safari only that when I trigger a dropdown in the fixed navbar that the font weight for ALL text in navbar changes, including the brand text.

Here is a screen shot of navbar BEFORE

[image: navbar BEFORE]

and AFTER:

[image: navbar AFTER hovering on dropdown menu]

I've included below the navbar text and custom CSS. Thanks for your help!

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Midge Raymond</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="hidden-sm"><a href="/">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bio.html">bio</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="/books"  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="500">books <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="/books/mylastcontinent.html">My Last Continent</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/books/forgettingenglish.html">Forgetting English</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/books/everydaywriting.html">Everyday Writing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/books/everydaybookmarketing.html">Everyday Book Marketing</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="/books"  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="500">other writing <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="/otherwriting/articles.html">Articles</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/otherwriting/shortstories.html">Short Stories</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/news.html">news & events</a></li>
        <li class="hidden-sm"><a href="/blog">blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

And CSS:

```
.navbar {
         min-height: 100px;
         padding-top: 15px; 
         margin-bottom: 5px;
         padding-left: 0px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
         margin-top: 40px; 

}

.navbar-brand {
        font-family: 'EB Garamond', 'Garamond', serif;
        font-size: 52px;
        margin-top: 15px; 
        margin-bottom: 10px; 
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: normal;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-brand {
        font-family: 'EB Garamond', 'Garamond', serif;
        font-size: 34px;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    margin-top: 15px; // Adjust toggle position
  }
  body { padding-top: 110px; }

}


.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
          color: #ffffff;
          font-weight: normal;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #488A87;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default {
        background-color: #073949;
        border-color: #aaaaaa;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
        color: white;
        font-size: 17px;
        padding-top: 10px;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
        background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

@media (min-width:1024px) { 
        .navbar > .container {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .navbar-header,.navbar-brand,.navbar .navbar-nav,.navbar .navbar-nav > li {
            float: none;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .collapse.navbar-collapse {
            float: none;
            width: auto;
            clear: none;
            text-align: center;
        }
}

.dropdown-menu {
        background: #f9f9f5;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add the following to your CSS file to fix this issue. It's a font-smoothing problem that occurs with `position: fixed` and Safari.

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

You can find more details regarding this fix and why it occurs [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11333).

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7njwmd1a/

Answer (score 0):

try 
font-weight: normal !important;

User developer tool(press F12) of browser to check which class is being added/removed when you click on drop-down and probably that will help to solve problem.

Comment: Thanks! This was going to be my fallback approach. Fortunately, font-smoothing was the issue.